# Convergence of complex series $\sum \frac{z^n}{\sin(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I started studying complex analysis out of interest recently, and there is a problem I just cannot figure out as much as I try.

This is about the radius of convergence of the following series :

$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{z^n}{\sin n}$$

Now, what I have established is that clearly, the series diverges in absolute value for $|z|>1$ by bounding downwards with $\sum_{n>0}{|z|^n}$

My intuition tells me this series should CONVERGE for $|z|<1$. However, I am not able to prove it. I tried using the definition of the radius of convergence, :

$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \left|\frac{1}{\sin n}  \right|^{1/n}.$$

However, I cannot prove that limit as $n\to\infty$ of $\sin(n)^{1/n}$ is indeed $1$. I know that the problem is that the adherence of set $\sin(n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $[-1;1]$ and I don't know how to deal with the subsequence $\sin(n_k)$ that tends to $0$.

I have also considered tried bounding the series, but to no avail. Is there any method I missed or do I have to find a way to compute the aforementioned limit ?

Comment: Knowing that $\pi$ has [finite irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure), you can bound $\lvert \sin n\rvert \geqslant c\cdot n^{-k}$, and that gives the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on the [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) of $\pi$.
If $x$ is an irrational number, the irrationality measure of $x$ is the number $\mu$ such that for all $\varepsilon>0$, and integers $p,q$ with large enough $q$, we have:
$$\left|x-\frac{p}{q}\right|>\frac{1}{q^{\mu+\varepsilon}}$$
We know that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is smaller than $7.7$. (Although, I do not know how to prove it, myself.)

In particular: $\left|\pi-\frac{p}{2q}\right|>\frac{1}{(2q)^8}$ for large enough $q$.

So $$\left|2q\pi-p\right|>(2q)^{-7} $$
For large enough $q$.

---

Let $n>0$
$$|\sin(n)| = |\sin(2q\pi - n)| = \sin|2q\pi-n| $$
Where $q$ is chosen such that $2q\pi-n$ is in $(-\pi,\pi]$. ($q\approx n/2\pi$)
$$|\sin(n)|>(2q)^{-7}$$
So $$\frac{x^n}{\sin(n)} = \mathcal O(x^n q^7) = \mathcal O(x^n n^7) $$
So it converges for $|x|<1$